# React: Conditionally changing image with customHook

Tags: reactjs, image, tailwind-css, conditional-operator, react-custom-hooks

So I have a custom hook that controls the theme (dark/light mode) using tailwind and I have two images that alternate between the two modes. I'm trying to get one to load for darkMode and one to load for lightMode but it doesn't seem to work. I have the FontAwesome icons changing from sun to moon, but the images won't switch.
This is the useTheme.tsx hook that changes the title image that controls `theme` and `changeTheme`. `changeTheme` is used in my Theme.tsx component and is essentially a basic button that calls the function onClick.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function useTheme() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (theme === 'dark') {
      document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
    }
    console.log(theme);
  }, [theme]);

  const changeTheme = () => {
    if (theme === 'light') {
      setTheme('dark');
    }
    if (theme === 'dark') {
      setTheme('light');
    }
  };

  return { theme, changeTheme };
}
```

This is the Title.tsx component where the image is supposed to change based on `theme`

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useTheme } from '../../hooks/ThemeHook';
export function Title() {
  const { theme } = useTheme();

  return (
    <NavLink to="/">
      {theme === 'dark' ? (
        <img
          src={'/signature_red.png'}
          alt="signature1"
          key={theme}
          className="min-w-[150px] max-w-[300px] w-1/3 h-[75px]"
        />
      ) : (
        <img
          src="/signature.png"
          alt="signature2"
          key={theme}
          className="min-w-[150px] max-w-[300px] w-1/3 h-[75px]"
        />
      )}
    </NavLink>
  );
}
```

I've tried messing around with it, removing the useEffect hook and only changing things in changeTheme, setting a helper variable in Title.tsx that gets passed to changeTheme to change the theme in the theme hook. and conditionally changing the src of one image (which I've learned react may not unmount/mount the new component unless the alt changes? which I've also tried) so I'm at a loss for what to try next. Thank you!

Comment: Can you create a [code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) for this ?

Comment: @ShivamJha I went to your link and very minimally created the example

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code... And I think you need to post a different link to your code sandbox with after you made your changes. You can't make changes to someone else's code sandbox

Comment: Is `theme` in `Title` component changing?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/elated-allen-s3jo97?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I hope that link works for you. theme does seem to change in useTheme.tsx as it gets logged in useEffect and as stated the sun and moon indicators do change with the click of the button. However, I do wonder if theme isn't being updated in the title/the title isn't being rerendered when theme does change.

Comment: It doesn't work because each component creates a new instance of the `useTheme` hook and the hook does not set a global state. If separate instances of a react hook shares a common state we would have a massive issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use in hook useTheme in Theme and Title, but is not the same hook,
you create two different hooks.

try this(just put the hook in there parent component):
[codesandboxexample](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-star-6cb5mu)